# Heap Sort in C++

Tags: c++, sorting, data-structures

Okay, so after struggling with trying to debug this, I have finally given up. I'm a beginner in C++ & Data Structures and I'm trying to implement Heap Sort in C++. The code that follows gives correct output on positive integers, but seems to fail when I try to enter a few negative integers.

Please point out ANY errors/discrepancies in the following code. Also, any other suggestions/criticism pertaining to the subject will be gladly appreciated.

```
//Heap Sort
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>
int a[50],n,hs;
void swap(int &x,int &y)
{
    int temp=x;
    x=y;
    y=temp;
}
void heapify(int x)
{
    int left=(2*x);
    int right=(2*x)+1;
    int large;
    if((left<=hs)&&(a[left]>a[x]))
    {
        large=left;
    }
    else
    {
        large=x;
    }
    if((right<=hs)&&(a[right]>a[large]))
    {
        large=right;
    }
    if(x!=large)
    {
        swap(a[x],a[large]);
        heapify(large);
    }
}
void BuildMaxHeap()
{
    for(int i=n/2;i>0;i--)
    {
        heapify(i);
    }
}
void HeapSort()
{
    BuildMaxHeap();
    hs=n;
    for(int i=hs;i>1;i--)
    {
        swap(a[1],a[i]);
        hs--;
        heapify(1);
    }
}
void main()
{
    int i;
    clrscr();
    cout<<"Enter length:\t";
    cin>>n;
    cout<<endl<<"Enter elements:\n";
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)       //Read Array
    {
        cin>>a[i];
    }
    HeapSort();
    cout<<endl<<"Sorted elements:\n";
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)       //Print Sorted Array
    {
        cout<<a[i];
        if(i!=n)
        {
            cout<<"\t";
        }
    }
    getch();
}
```

I've been reading up on Heap Sort but I'm not able to grasp most of the concept, and without that I'm not quite able to fix the logical error(s) above.

Comment: I've added the [tag:homework] tag.  If this isn't, feel free to remove it.

Comment: what happens when you use negative numbers on input?  Give an example input and output.

Comment: Get a copy of *Programming Pearls* by Jon Bentley, and read the chapter on heaps. See http://product.half.ebay.com/Programming-Pearls-by-Jon-Louis-Bentley-1985-Paperback/72143&tg=info

Comment: I don't see how something like this could work with positive numbers but not with negatives... It probably doesn't work with positives either, you just haven't noticed it yet.

Comment: Here is the sample output of when it works correctly:

Enter length:   10

Enter elements:
10      9       8       7       6       5       4       3       2       1

Sorted elements:
1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9       10

Comment: @yi_H And here the output is incorrect. Notice that all the numbers are sorted except the last one.
Enter length:   10

Enter elements:
-300    -250    -500    -20     0       0       1       75      100     200

Sorted elements:
-500    -250    -20     0       0       1       75      100     200     -300

Comment: First of all a heap is not sorted. Your "Print sorted array" comment is not true.

Comment: @LouFranco Sample output is above. Sorry for the redundant comment. I forgot to tag you on the previous one, and I believe we can't edit comments after a while.

Comment: @Siddharth Chatterjee: add 1000 to every element when feeding input. If I'm right that will fail as well, yet no negative numbers.

Comment: What on earth is `<iostream.h>`?

Comment: @yi_H Yes, you're correct!

Enter length:   10

Enter elements:
700     750     500     980     1000    1000    1001    1075    1100    1200

Sorted elements:
500     750     980     1000    1000    1001    1075    1100    1200    700

Comment: @Karl My grand-grand-father's `iostream`.

Comment: @pmr It was meant facetiously, to point out the deprecation. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You set `hs` after calling `BuildMaxHeap`. Switch those two lines.

```
hs=n;
BuildMaxHeap();
```

Comment: Or make `hs=n;` the first line of  `BuildMaxHeap` (after a look into my algorithm book)

Answer (score 1):

When I implemented my own heapsort, I had to be extra careful about the indices; if you index from 0, children are 2x+1 and 2x+2, when you index from 1, children are 2x and 2x+1. There were a lot of silent problems because of that. Also, every operation needs a single well-written siftDown function, that is vital.

Open up Wikipedia at the Heapsort and Binary heap articles and try to rewrite it more cleanly, following terminology and notation where possible. [Here is my implementation](http://frigocoder.dyndns.org/svn/Frigo/Trash/HeapSort.hpp) as well, perhaps it can help.

Hmmm now that I checked your code better, are you sure your siftDown/heapify function restricts sifting to the current size of the heap?

**Edit: Found the problem! You do not initialize `hs` to `n` before calling BuildMaxHeap().**

Comment: Thank you. Your implementation looks great. Looking through the terminology and notations now.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's because you're 1-basing the array. There's probably a case where you're accidentally 0-basing it but I can't spot it in the code offhand.

Comment: I suspected the same thing initially. That maybe one of the conditional statements accidentally 0-bases the array. But I've tried looking through it a few times. Can't seem to spot it!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example if it helps.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void max_heapify(std::vector<int>& arr, int index, int N) {
    // get the left and right index
    int left_index = 2*index + 1;
    int right_index = 2*index + 2;

    int largest = 0;
    if (left_index < N && arr[left_index] > arr[index]) {
        // the value at the left_index is larger than the 
        // value at the index of the array
        largest = left_index;
    } else {
        largest = index;
    }

    if (right_index < N && arr[right_index] > arr[largest]) {
        // the value at the right_index is larger than the
        // value at the index of the array
        largest = right_index;
    }

    // check if largest is still the index, if not swap
    if (index != largest) {
        // swap the value at index with value at largest
        int temp = arr[largest];
        arr[largest] = arr[index];
        arr[index] = temp;

        // once swap is done, do max_heapify on the index
        max_heapify(arr, largest, N);
    }
}

void build_max_heap(std::vector<int>& arr, int N) {
    // select all the non-leaf except the root and max_heapify them
    for (int i = N/2 - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        max_heapify(arr, i, N);
    }
}

void heap_sort(std::vector<int>& arr) {
    int N = arr.size();
    int heap_size = N;
    // build the max heap
    build_max_heap(arr, N);

    // once max heap is built,
    // to sort swap the value at root and last index
    for (int i = N - 1; i > 0; --i) {
        // swap the elements
        int root = arr[0];
        arr[0] = arr[i];
        arr[i] = root;

        // remove the last node
        --heap_size;

        // perform max_heapify on updated heap with the index of the root
        max_heapify(arr, 0, heap_size);
    }
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> data = {5,1,8,3,4,9,10};

    // create max heap from the array
    heap_sort(data);

    for (int i : data) {
        cout << i << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# include <iostream>   //Desouky//
 using namespace std;

void reheapify(int *arr, int n, int i)
{
int parent = i; // initilaize largest as parent/root
int child1 = 2 * i + 1; // to get first chid 
int child2 = 2 * i + 2; // to get second child

if (child1 < n && arr[child1] > arr[parent]) // if child2 >  parent
{
    parent = child1;
}
//if child > the parent 
if (child2 < n && arr[child2] > arr[parent])
{
    parent = child2;
}
// if the largest  not the parent 
if (parent != i)
{
    swap(arr[i], arr[parent]);
    // Recursively heapify the affected sub-tree
    reheapify(arr, n, parent);
}

}
 void heapsort(int *arr, int n)
 {
 // build a heap
for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    reheapify(arr, n, i);
}
// One by one extract an element from heap
for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    // Move current root to end
    swap(arr[0], arr[i]);

    // call max heapify on the reduced heap
    reheapify(arr, i, 0);
 }
 }

 int main()
 {

freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);
int n;
cin >> n;
int* arr = new int[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    cin >> arr[i];
}
heapsort(arr, n);
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    cout << arr[i] << " ";
}

 }
```